# How do you delete a test suite in testRigor?

Tags: testrigor

My team and I have recently setup testRigor and in doing so created some extraneous test suites. Combing through the dashboard we haven't found an obvious way to remove the extra suites. How can test suites be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it should be requested on your Slack, the delete test suite functionality is coming up soon.

Comment: Hi Team,Does the delete test suite functionality is in place?